# Why doesn't my Wordpress admin dashboard have a "Comments" menu item?

Tags: php, wordpress, wp-admin

I'm an administrator user on my site, and I can see the small "speech bubble" comments menu at the top admin bar, and I use it to moderate comments, but my sidebar does not show a "comments" menu.

I need to be able to see it to work with a the wpDiscuz plugin.

I've looked through functions.php and wp-admin/menu.php, and I can't find anything anomalous about them that would indicate they've been used to hide the comments menu.

I haven't seen anything similar to what is referenced [here](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/remove_menu_page) and [here](https://www.powderkegwebdesign.com/quickly-easily-remove-comments-backend-wordpress/).

I'm stumped. Any advice?

Comment: Tried disabling all of your plugins?

Comment: yes, to no avail.

Comment: How about changing themes? Maybe using the default WP theme.

Comment: Ugh, never mind. Found the plugin that did it.